# Word Templates not showing up in SharePoint/Teams after being added via PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate, word-template

I've been trying to setup a flow that automatically mirrors (read: copies and creates new) Word templates from one Teams Channel to another.
The goal is to have them appear in the "+ new"-dropdown in sharepoint and teams (see screenshot).
["+new"-dropdown in Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZbVg.png)

I believe I managed to find the path to the folder in which to put the template-file, which is: **https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSiteName/Freigegebene Dokumente/Forms**
The "Freigegebene Dokumente" should be "shared documents" in english afaik.
Here comes the caveat:
When I upload a template-file via powerautomate, they do not show up in the "+ new"-dropdown. When I then try to manually add the same file via the "+ new"-dropdown, it tells me that a file with that name already exists.

Am I missing something? I fully expected this to just *work*.

What I am trying to get running so that the bigger solution can work is this:

1. Manually trigger a Microsoft PowerAutomate Cloudflow
2. Get information about a specific file in SharePoint (a .dotx MS-Word template)
3. Get the content of that specific file
4. Create a new File in the */Forms folder with the same name and content as seen in the screenshot.
5. Be able to create a new File in SharePoint (and Teams) from that template via the "+new"-dropdown

The two parameters used are:

```
@outputs('Dateieigenschaften_abrufen')?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}']
```

and

```
@body('Dateiinhalt_abrufen')
```

[Screenshot of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYIho.png)

After running this flow, I expect to have a new template to choose from in the "+new"-dropdown in SharePoint. That is **not** the case.

I know that there is something uploaded, because if I try to manually add the template via the "+new"-dropdown
[manual upload in "+new"-dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bz30.png)
 
I get this error message:
[Error Message on manual upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6QjG.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the repro steps what exactly you are trying?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I tried explaining everything as best as I could, if there is any information I could still supply to make things clearer - please let me know! Thanks so much for your response :)

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed explanation. We tried to repro the issue by creating a PowerAutomate flow as mentioned https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZMYF.png . After running the flow, it gives success message banner https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoNNm.png. However, on navigating to SharePoint/Teams Files section in the +New dropdown menu we could not see the created file. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjrR.png

Comment: We have raised this issue in PowerAutomate forum. Please refer [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Word-Templates-not-showing-up-in-SharePoint-Teams-after-being/m-p/1985040#M36305) thread for further updates. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @DerSeestern - Did you get a change to the way suggested by community support person? https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Word-Templates-not-showing-up-in-SharePoint-Teams-after-being/m-p/1986952/highlight/true#M36334